# Setting the app's screen

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I set the screen of the app so it doesn't take up the whole screen of device? Perhaps even half of the screen or less than that?

Answer (score 0):

you should research how to use layout in Android (Linear Layout, Relative Layout, Table Layout..)